# How to make a grid in threejs like the attached image?

Tags: three.js

I want to make a interface like the attached image. But i am unable to get started.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsXbx.png

Comment: you mean with the halo as well?

Comment: there is a grid helper (http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Helpers/GridHelper), but maybe you want to add some shading effect to it, this is just another question ;)

Comment: GridHelper [√]. thanks @juagicre

Comment: If you wanted the glow effect, A simple plane with a custom shadermaterial might be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For basic grid ([GridHelper](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/GridHelper)) is your friend.

Comment: Link is broken, [this one](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/helpers/GridHelper) is working.

Comment: @fsinisi90 Thanks for posting the updated link ! I edited the post so that the correct link is now shown